# Converting date string (YYYY/YYYY_mm.mdf) into useable date Python

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I have a csv file with 10,000 date strings that look like 2000/2000_03.mdf and I need only the year and month for each string. I've tried using:

```
datetime.strptime('2000/2000_03.mdf', '%Y/%Y_%m')
```

but this returns an error. I'm guessing it has something to do with the mdf on the end, and the repeated year, but I'm not sure how to eliminate those parts of the string to get only the times I want. Is there an easier way to just extract the month and year?

Comment: so put `.mdf` into your format string... that's why there's `%` in there - to difference between `Y` as format character, and `Y` as regular character in a string.

Answer (score 6):

If you're absolutely sure that the year will always be repeated properly, I'd just....skip the year.

```
s = '2000/2000_03.mdf'.split('/')
d = datetime.strptime(s[1], '%Y_%m.mdf')
if int(s[0]) != d.year:
    #uh, that file is confused. Do something?
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with this. The first is the `.mdf` on the end, which as @marc-b pointed out, can be fixed by adding it to your format string.

However, if you just do that you'll find that you still get a `ValueError`:

```
error: redefinition of group name 'Y' as group 2; was group 1
```

You cannot match the same group twice with `strptime`. If your data is consistent in the format you presented, then you can use `string.split` to extract the second portion and read from that:

```
basename = '2000/2000_03.mdf'.split('/')[1]
datetime.strptime(basename, '%Y_%m.mdf')
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple regex works in this case and it should be more efficient than `strptime()` and easier to read than `.split()`-based solutions:

```
import re
from datetime import date

def parse_date(path):
    """Return date stored in the *path* or None on any error."""
    try:
         year1, year2, month = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', path))
         if year1 == year2:
             return date(year2, month, 1)
    except ValueError:
         pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just slice the string:

```
datetime.strptime('2000/2000_03.mdf'[5:-4], '%Y_%m')
```

This yields the following:

```
datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution to the problem of multiple strftime directives in a string is to use a regex as outlined in jfs's answer.

If you scrunch your face like I do when looking at regexes you can do the same more legibly using the [parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/) module:

```py
from parse import parse
from datetime import datetime

parsed_vals = parse('{dt_Y:4d}/{dt_Y:4d}_{dt_m:2d}.mdf', '2000/2000_03.mdf')
# <Result () {'dt_m': 3, 'dt_Y': 2000}>

datetime(parsed_vals['dt_Y'], parsed_vals['dt_m'], 1)
# datetime.datetime(2000, 3, 1, 0, 0)
```